# Ranking with subsets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rank

I'm trying to rank values and have managed to work out how to sort ties. My data looks at the total number of entries, ranks based on that and if there is a tie it looks to the next column of values to sort them out. However, I have two classes (East and West I've called them) of data within my dataset and want to rank them both separately (but stick to the rules above). So, if I had seven entries, 3 of them West and 4 of the East, I want West to have ranking 1,2,3 based on all the values that lie in that subset and East would have ranking 1,2,3,4. Can you explain what your formula is doing so I can understand how to apply your answer better in the future.

Effectively I'm asking what formula needs to go in achieve my result.

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few related ways to do this, most involving `SUMPRODUCT`. If you don't like the solution below and would like to research other ways/explanations, try searching for "rankif".

[image]

The function looks up the `Class` and `Value` columns and, for every value in those columns, returns a `TRUE` or 1 if the current `Class` is a match AND if its `Value` is larger than the current `Value`, `False` or 0 if otherwise. The `SUM` adds up all these 1s, and the `1+` is for decoration. Remember to enter as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> before dragging down.

I used the array formula and `SUM` above to explain, but the following also works and might even be faster since it's not an array formula. It's the same idea, except we hijack `SUMPRODUCT`'s ability to spit out a single value from an array.

`=1+SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8=A2)*($B$2:$B$8>B2))`

**EDIT**

To extend the rank-if, you could add more subsets to rank by multiplying more conditions:
[image]

You can also easily add tiebreakers by adding another `SUMPRODUCT` to treat the ties as an additional subset:
[image]

The first `SUMPRODUCT` is the 'base rank', while the second `SUMPRODUCT` is tiebreaker #1.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Can I add a little more complexity. Assume you had another set of values in column C (and your ranking column was D). If I wanted to use this this column as a tie breaker if there was a tie in Column B (for example B2 was also 56). Can you do this using a non array formula?

Comment: @PaulWedlock Edited the post to show how to extend to tiebreakers. Please accept if that solves your question!